# javax.persistence.NoResultException object exists in cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss5.x

I'm using JBoss 5 with Hibernate.

In single session, I'm creating new Entity object than execute `EntityManager.persist()`. 
After (before executing `flush()`) I could find it by PK using method `EntityManager.find()`, and I see the the object exists in cache (`EntityManager.contains(o)` returns true), but I could not load it by executing namedQuery or query..

Why?

```
/* I have a Entity "DocumentsHistory" and "Documents" they are related (DocumentsHistory contains docId refers to Documents.docId (PK) and Documents contains lastDhId refers to DocumentsHistory.docHistId) */
// I'm working with example of Documents - doc
// I need to create new example of DocumentsHistory and than later in the same transaction select it 

// Creation of new DocumentsHistory

DocumentsHistory dh = new DocumentsHistory();
dh.setDocId(doc.getDocId); // Link with current example of Documents
dh.setType("REFF"); // set String value
dh.setRefId( id );  // set Long value

em.persit(dh); // persist new object

doc.setLastDhId(dh.docHistId);
em.merge(doc); // persist existing object

//... than later in the same transaction I'm trying to execute named Query 

DocumentsHistory dh = (DocumentsHistory)    em.createNamedQuery("DocumentsHistory.findByDocIdType")
                                .setParameter("docId", doc.getDocId())
                                .setParameter("type", "REFF")
                                .getSingleResult();

// and it throws NoResultException
// but:

em.find( DocumentsHistory.class, doc.getLastDhId() ); // returns object
```

=========================================================================================
I also create a simple JPA test (without JBoss) and it works

```
em.getTransaction().begin();

printAll( Participants.class, em );// prints the whole table

Participants part = new Participants();
part.setCode( "PPPPPPPPPPPP" );
em.persist( part );
printAll( Participants.class, em );  
// FIND new 
Participants p = (Participants)em.createNamedQuery("Participants.findByParticipantCode" ).setParameter( "participantCode", "PPPPPPPPPPPP" ).getSingleResult(); 

System.out.println( "NEW PARTICIPANT: " + p.toString() ); // Prints new object

em.getTransaction().rollback();

@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTICIPANTS")
@NamedQuery(name = "Participants.findByParticipantCode", query = "SELECT p FROM Participants p WHERE p.code = :participantCode ")
public class Participants implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="VID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="VID",sequenceName="VID")
    @Column(name = "PARTICIPANT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long participantId;

        @Column(name = "PARTICIPANT_CODE", nullable = false)
        private String code;

    public Long getParticipantId() {
        return participantId;
    }

    public void setParticipantId(Long participantId) {
        this.participantId = participantId;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ParticId: " + this.participantId + "; code: " + this.code + ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please post the relevant parts of it.

Comment: It will be very diffucult because my code in several files and contains a lot of unusefull details, but I tried to do it in principle

Comment: IT's better still :) It is often pointless to discuss the assumptions one has about his own code. The truth is in the code itself. I have glanced over the code and IMO you are querying for two different things: while you use `doc.getDocId` in your first query, you use `dh.docHistId`. This probably results in different SQL statements. Have you checked your parameters? Both queries should use the 2nd lvl cache, so I cannot imagine a scenario where two equivalent queries could return different results.

Comment: My theory regarding your second (working) example is that "something" (either the sequence generator or your `printAll` method) flushes the context and thus creates the entity in the database. Breakpoint the code before the `createNamedQuery` call and check if the value appears in the database.

Comment: Putting all the debugging aside: what you're seeing in the jboss case is expected behavior. JPA provider have a internally managed context and which may contain "unfinished" entities. Unless you `commit()`/`flush()`, your queries have no business using these entities as they haven't been checked by the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) checks the current persistence context (as a kind of first level cache) before going to the database. When you call `persist()` you're adding to that context.

Here's the `find()` javadoc (emphasis mine):

> Find by primary key. Search for an entity of the specified class and primary key. **If the entity instance is contained in the persistence context, it is returned from there.**

and `contains()`:

> Check if the instance is a managed entity instance belonging to the current persistence context.

In contrast, your named query must access the database, which at this point knows nothing about your cached entity. As you noticed you need to sync your cache with the database by calling `flush()`.

Comment: When I'm calling:

DocumentsHistory dh = (DocumentsHistory)em.find( DocumentsHistory.class, doc.getLastDhId() );

em.contains(dh); // returns true

Comment: I also tried to peform the test with the same databace but without Jboss, I create simple JPA project with hibernate 4.3.4 and try to create object, execute persist and the execute query before clousing transaction...
and in such case query return new object

Comment: @user not sure about your jpa project, can you edit your question to include the persist, query, commit sequence?

Comment: My question contains that sequence, I making new object and modiffication of exesting object and after making query, I'm executing commit only at the end of all logic if no exeception thrown.

persist -> merge -> query .... commit (flush)

Comment: @user please post your code, then. Also have you checked the database state during your method execution? Maybe your sample project caused a flush before the final commit.

Comment: here is the code of the simple test:
`em.getTransaction().begin();

printAll( Participants.class, em );// prints the whole table

Participants part = new Participants();
part.setCode( "PPPPPPPPPPPP" );
em.persist( part );

printAll( Participants.class, em );

// FIND new
Participants p = (Participants)em.createNamedQuery("Participants.findByParticipantCode" ).setParameter( "participantCode", "PPPPPPPPPPPP" ).getSingleResult();
System.out.println( "NEW PARTICIPANT: " + p.toString() );
em.getTransaction().rollback();`

Comment: Again, please edit your answer to include the code. It makes it much easier to read. Also, please include the entity classes with at least their `@Id` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st and 2nd level cache of Hibernate stores the objects by their identifiers. For this reason the cache is not really usable for queries in a general way. First Hibernate always need to execute your query on the database to retrieve the ids of the matching entities. The result of this query (at this point) is just a list of ids! Only after this Hibernate is able to use the cache and lookup the objects by their ids. With no flush being called your query returns no ids so the cache is not even touched.

Comment: Is any way to execute query and take data from cache?

Comment: No, the query is always executed on the database. What you have described is the normal behaviour with JPA/Hibernate.